# q promise and map doesn't change after iteration

Tags: q

I'm using Q Promises to retrieve data from my redis repository. The problem I'm having, is that through each iteration, the array object (localEncounter) I'm using to store data returned from the chained functions is never updated at each iteration. Previously, I tried to solve this with a foreach loop and spread but the results were the same.

How should I correct this so that localEncounter is updated at each iteration, and ultimately localEncounters contains correct data when returned?  Thank you.

```
var localEncounters = [];
            var localEncounter = {};

            Promise.all(ids.map(function(id) {
                return localEncounter, getEncounter(id, client)
                    .then(function (encounter) {
                        encounterObject = encounter;

                        //set the fields for the return object
                        localEncounter['encounterid'] = encounterObject[f_id];
                        localEncounter['screeningid'] = encounterObject[f_screening_id];
                        localEncounter['assessmentid'] = encounterObject[f_clinical_assessment_id];
                        localEncounter['psychevalid'] = encounterObject[f_psych_eval_id];

                        //get screening
                        return getScreening(encounterObject[f_screening_id], client);
                    })
                    .then(function (screening) {
                        //set the fields for the return object
                        localEncounter['screeningbegintime'] = screening[f_begin_time];
                        //get assessment                        
                        return getAssessment(localEncounter['assessmentid'], client);
                    })
                    .then(function (assessment) {
                        //set the fields for the return object
                        localEncounter['assessmentbegintime'] = assessment[f_begin_time];
                        //get psycheval
                        //localEncounters.push(assessment);
                        return getPsychEval(localEncounter['psychevalid'], client);
                    })
                    .then(function (psychEval) {
                        //set the fields for the return object
                        localEncounter['assessmentbegintime'] = psychEval[f_begin_time];

                        localEncounters.push(localEncounter);

                    }
                    , function (reason) {
                        console.log(reason); // display reason why the call failed;
                        reject(reason, 'Something went wrong creating the encounter!');
                    })

            })).then(function(results) {
                // results is an array of names
                console.log('done ');

                resolve(localEncounters);
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I only needed to move the declaration of localEncounter inside the map iterator

before:

```
var localEncounter = {};

        Promise.all(ids.map(function(id) {
```

after:

```
            Promise.all(ids.map(function(id) {
```

`var localEncounter = {};`

This now allows that each id iteration gets its own localEncounter object.